# Casting error in Realm migration to change property Double to List<CustomObject>

Tags: ios, swift, realm, database-migration, realm-migration

What I need is to create a migration to change `discount:Double` to `discounts:List<Discount>()` based on the following code.

#### Here is the Existing Object: This is how my `Realm Object` looks right now.

```
class Item:Object{
    @objc dynamic var itemName:String = "Some Name"
    @objc dynamic var discount:Double = 0 // need to change this property
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to make the change.

#### New Object:

```
class Discount: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name:String = "Discount Name"
    @objc dynamic var discount:Double = 0.0
}
```

#### Modified Object with `one-to-many`relation.

```
class Item:Object{
    @objc dynamic var itemName:String = "Some Name"
    let discounts = List<Discount>()
}
```

#### Migration

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 3,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Item.className()) { oldObject, newObject in

                    let oldDiscount = oldObject!["discount"] as! Double

                    let discount = Discount()
                    discount.amount = oldDiscount

                    let discounts = newObject!["discounts"] as! List<Discount>
                    discounts.append(discount)
            }
        }
    })
```

I'm getting error:

> Could not cast value of type `RealmSwift.List<RealmSwift.DynamicObject>(0x1c8910068)` to `RealmSwift.List<AppName.Discount> (0x1c890f6a0)`.

Again, the question is, how can I create a migration to change `discount:Double` to `discounts:List<Discount>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate the discount property into the new discount list as a List like [oldDiscount]

Here's the code. I renamed some of the objects to make it a bit more clear as the re-use of the word 'discount' to refer to the class and the property was confusing.

```
let vers = UInt64(1)
let config = Realm.Configuration( schemaVersion: vers, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
     if (oldSchemaVersion < vers) {
         print("performing migration")
         migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ItemClass.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
            let oldDiscount = oldItem!["discount"] as? Double ?? 0.0

            let d = DiscountClass()
            d.name = "Test"
            d.discount = oldDiscount

            newItem!["discountList"] = [d]
         }
     } else {
        print("no migration needed")
    }
 })
```